# Prove That $|a +b| = |a| +|b|$ if $a$ and $b$ Have Same Signs, And $|a +b| < |a| + |b|$ if $a$ and $b$ Have Opposite Signs

Tags: functions, absolute-value

**My Proof:**

$|a +b| = |a| +|b|$ ..... $(i)$

$|a +b| < |a| + |b|$ ..... $(i)$

***If $'a'$ and $'b'$ have same signs:***

Let $a$ and $b$ be equal to $-x$. Replacing $a$ and $b$ with $-x$ in the equation $(i)$, we get the following result:

$|-x +(-x)| = |-x| + |-x|$

$|-x -x| = -(-x) -(-x)$

$|-2x| = x +x$

$-(-2x) = 2x$

$2x = 2x$ ..... Proved

***If $'a'$ and $'b'$ have opposite signs:***

Let $a = x$ and $b = -x$. Then, by replacing $a$ and $b$ with $x$ and $-x$ respectively in the inequality $(i)$, we get the following result:

$|x +(-x)| < |x| + |-x|$

$|x -x| < x -(-x)$

$|0| < x +x$

$0 < 2x$ ..... Proved

> Is this way valid for proving what has been asked to prove in the
>   problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, in your proof you've assumed either $a=b$ (in the first part), or $a=-b$ (in the second part.  The reason is you've used the same letter, $x$, for two things.  The inequality should be true even without this assumption.

Comment: So is my proof wrong?

Comment: Yes it's wrong.

Comment: Can those voting to close please explain to the OP how they can improve the question? (Also, questions asking "can you check my proof" are not generally frowned upon, no?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the definition of absolute value, i.e.

$|x| := \left\{\begin{array}{l}x, \mbox{if } x > 0 \\ -x, \mbox{if } x < 0 \end{array}\right.$

Next consider four cases:

Case 1. $a, b > 0$

Then $|a| = a$ and $|b| = b$. Further, $|a + b| = a + b$. Can you finish the proof for this?

Case 2. $a, b < 0$

Then $|a| = -a$ and $|b| = -b$. More so, $|a + b| = -(a + b)$. And so on...

Case 3. $a < 0 < b$.

Then $|a| = -a > a$ and $|b| = b$...

Case 4. $b < 0 < a$.

Similar to the previous case.

p.s. Of course one can reduce further the cases, but I think for now it is best that you consider all cases...

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, you assumed your equation was true.

However if you first prove that your equation is true for $a$ and $b$ positive, then using your "$(-x)$ method" would be the right way to show it for negative $a$ and $b$ (considering you use $(-x)$ and $(-y)$ instead of $(-x)$ alone).

Same thing for the other equation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is incomplete. $a$ and $b$ having the same sign does not imply $a=b$, nor does $a$ and $b$ having opposite signs imply $a=-b$.

Try considering the following cases separately:

1. $a>0$ and $b>0$
2. $a>0$ and $b<0$
3. $a<0$ and $b>0$
4. $a<0$ and $b<0$

Comment: Or he could only do two different cases, and then show the two others by saying $\cases{a'=-a \\ b'=-b}$ ;)

Comment: @Dolma True ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Use Real number line .**[Motivation from your previous question]**

- $a, b$ be two points on opposite side of zero. Then $|a+b|$= distance between $a$ and $(-b)$ .Now as they are of opposite sign then $a$, $(-b)$ are on same sides of $0$. As $|x|$ represent the distance from origin. You get $|a+b|=||a|-|b||$
- Otherwise you get reverse.$|a+b|=|a|+|b|$. if $a,b$ are on same
  sides of real line.

Comment: That's a nice proof

Comment: Yes, I got the motivation from his last question instead. :P

Comment: Oh yeah I remember now, well spotted :)

Comment: Your first point is wrong. You need absolute value around the RHS too. For example, $|1 - 2 | \neq |1| - | -2|$.

Comment: @exploringnet -1 I don't see any thing wrong with the question statement. However, your statement is incorrect. It doesn't matter if you think it's an obviously incorrect statement under certain situations. You should clear that up.

Comment: @CalvinLin did it. see now.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this problem has eight cases.  $(a+b)$ could be positive or negative, $a$ could be positive or negative, and $b$ could be positive or negative.

However:

1. If $a,b$ are the same sign, then $(a+b)$ is that same sign.  This eliminates two of the cases.
2. If $a$ is positive and $b$ is negative (regardless of what $a+b$ is), we may swap the roles of $a$ and $b$; so this case is identical to when $a$ is negative and $b$ is positive.  This eliminates two more cases.

This leaves four cases to consider; two more are derived from these, and two are impossible.

1. $a>0, b>0, a+b>0$
2. $a<0, b<0, a+b<0$
3. $a>0, b<0, a+b>0$
4. $a>0, b<0, a+b<0$

With a bit of care one could combine cases 3 and 4 as well, but the important thing is that in these cases we may eliminate all absolute value symbols.